# Not able to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Java process

Tags: java, linux, dll, csh

I am trying to call my linux executable from shell script. Before calling this executable, I want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with specific values. My shell script is as below:

Parent.sh (contains 2 lines)

```
   - source set_env.sh 
   - executable.so
```

Set_env.sh

```
   - setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /proj/something
```

On manually executing Parent.sh scipt from linux console, the executable.so is called with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly. But after integrating it wiht java code as:

```
String[] commandArray ={"Parent.sh"};
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process javap = runtime.exec(commandArray);
javap.waitFor();
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set for executable.so

I hope description is clear :)

Please let know whats wrong in the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dunes answer solves your problem, but I would strongly suggest a different approach in this particular case. Instead of relying on a shell to set the environment arguments, you should do this in your Java code. This way you don't need to know which shells exist on the system and what their language is, it will just work on all platforms.

To do this, you can use the `Runtime.exec(String[] cmd, String[] environment)` overload ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)). As the second parameter you can pass an array which contains all the environment variables the subprocess will see.

A little bit nicer even is the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("executable.so");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/proj/something");
Process javap = pb.start();
javap.waitFor();
```

This way, the subprocess will inherit all environment variables from the Java process, and additionally have the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable set.

Comment: added environment array for LD_LIBRARY_PATH and its working fine. Now I am not at all dependent on shell iterpreters. Thanks Dune and Philipp for your valuable answers which took some 6-7 hours on debugging but not able to get to this.

Answer (score 1):

Are  you sure the subprocess is using csh? If it starts up using bash or something else then this would prevent the script from working (but not to throw an  IOException).

You should really aad a hashbang line as the very first line of your script to state which shell interpreter you wish to use.

eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh
```

Comment: thanks a lot... it worked at first shot.. AMAZING!!!! Yes currently I am testing on csh. Can you please let know how to check available shell interpretor on current running lunux at run time in java so I can modify this .sh file at run time.