# How to load android libraries when running binary files?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, linker, makefile

So, I have this executable binary file that references some libraries. When I try to run it with runtime.exec(), it gives me an error on the error stream saying:

```
link_image[1891]:  7176 could not load needed library 'XXX.so' for 'YYY' (load_library[1093]: Library 'XXX.so' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

I have the `XXX.so` library but I have no idea where I should place it relative to the binary `YYY`. I want this to work for unrooted device.

Btw, I'm not very good with the building stuff in general, so if you think there's something wrong I did when I built the binary, feel free to point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices

- build this binary with -static flag, I think this is the best way
- you can use dlopen to load this library dynamicly, such as

```
void *g_handle = NULL;
g_handle = dlopen("/system/lib/libskia.so", RTLD_LAZY);
_skFT_Init_FreeType = dlsym(g_handle, "FT_Init_FreeType");

/**do something */

dlclose(g_handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934668 where yours truly proposed  wrapper to set [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80) in a generic way. You can use [**ProcessBuilder**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) with modified environment, too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962189/192373.

Comment: Oh! I've been looking around on how to set environment variables in Java for so long! Thanks!